# Modifying the Body of PHP's SoapClient Message

Tags: php, .net, wcf, soap

Is it possible to modify the body of a PHP `SoapClient` request such that the soap parameters are included inside the method node?

This probably requires some background.

I'm working with a SOAP 1.2 web service built in .NET and WCF.

PHP's `SoapClient` and this service did not want to talk to one another.  With some judicious use of `SoapHeader` and `SoapParam` objects, I've worked through most of the issues, but there's one problem remaining that I haven't been able to figure out an elegant solution for. I was hoping someone on Stack Overflow had an answer.

According to the web services documentation, this service expects a soap body that looks something like this

```
<soap:Body> 
    <ns1:GetProductList>
        <ns1:PartnerID>xxxx</ns1:PartnerID>
        <ns1:PartnerPassword>xxxx</ns1:PartnerPassword>
        <ns1:DateStart>2013-07-01</ns1:DateStart>
        <ns1:DateEnd>2013-10-01</ns1:DateEnd>            
    </ns1:GetProductList> 
</soap:Body>
```

However, PHP's `SoapClient` sends a body that looks more like this

```
<soap:Body> 
    <ns1:GetProductList/>        
    <ns1:PartnerID>xxxx</ns1:PartnerID>
    <ns1:PartnerPassword>xxxx</ns1:PartnerPassword>
    <ns1:DateStart>2013-07-01</ns1:DateStart>
    <ns1:DateEnd>2013-10-01</ns1:DateEnd>                    
</soap:Body>
```

That is, instead of the parameters being inside the `GetProductList` method, they're nodes at the same depth level as `<ns1:GetProductList/>`.

Now, I can fix this is a super hacky way by using my own version of the `SoalClient` class (`CustomSoapClient`) with a redefined `__doRequest`

```
//this code snippet is released under the shame license.  You may reuse
//it provided you leave this comment in place and acknowledge what an awful
//solution regular expressing string replacing the soap message is
class CustomSoapClient extends SoapClient
{
    function __doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way = 0) 
    {
        $request = preg_replace('%(<ns1:GetProductList/>)(.+?)</env:Body>%',
        '<ns1:GetProductList>$2</ns1:GetProductList></env:Body>',$request);            
        return parent::__doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way = 0);
    }    
}
```

However, that's clearly not optimal.

I looking for some magic incantation to use with the `SoapClient` class that would stick those parameters inside the method node, or a well tested and proven general piece of code for modifying things in `__doRequest` to the same end. Alternate solutions I haven't thought of are more than welcome.